# Android C2DM registration failure

Tags: android, android-c2dm

C2DM registration from my android app fails with an error 'SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE'. From what i understand this is because the server returned an error.

**Is there a way to figure out if the google C2DM server is running?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess i figured out the problem... I didnt send the '@gmail.com' part of the sender Id while trying to register

Answer (score 0):

Well, one easy way would be to test with a Chrome2Phone message.

If you want to provide more details about where you're getting this error (emulator vs device, production vs local), might be able to help a bit more.

Comment: Guess i figured out the problem... I didnt send the '@gmail.com' part of the sender Id while trying to register